# Tool for editing dimens.xml (Android)

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I'm working on a project where I have many `dimens.xml` files for the different screen sizes and asked myself whether there is a tool like the Sequoyah Localization Editor but for dimensions.

To be more precise, what I am searching for is a tool which shows a grid for all defined dimensions where the coloumns represent the different dimen.xml files.

Does anybody of you know such a tool?

[image: Seqouyah Localization Editor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause I didn't find a tool and obviously nobody knows one I decided to write my own tool based on the Seqouyah Localization Editor. Actually thinks are hacked together pretty dirty, but it works for me. For sure code will be available on GitHub soon.

**WARNING: THIS TOOL IS PRETTY MUCH NOT TESTED - USE IT ON YOUR OWN RISK.**
I'm not responsible for any failures provided by the tool, which might be wrong data, data loss or IDE crashes.

Till then feel free to download and install and test the **Android Dimensions Editor** in your Eclipse.

Eclipse Update Site is http://eclipse.allyourapps.net/updates/

[image: Eclipse Update Site]

After installation you should be able to open `dimens.xml` files by right click **"Open -> Open With -> Other -> Dimensions Editor"**

[image: Open dimens.xml with Dimensions Editor]

Last but not least a screenshot of the editor itself:
[image: Dimensions Editor in action]